# How to pass an array of Objects into a format jQuery Ajax understands?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have an asmx web service that has the following function:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public List<Tag> GetTags()
    {
        List<Tag> TagList = new List<Tag>();

        DataTable dt = Helpers.Tags.GetTags();

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            Tag t = new Tag();
            t.TagName = dr["Tag"].ToString();
            t.TagDescription = dr["Description"].ToString();
            TagList.Add(t);
        }

        return TagList;
    }
```

Here's the Tag Class:

```
    public class Tag
    {
        public string TagName { get; set; }
        public string TagDescription { get; set; }
    }
```

The GetTags() method returns an object List of Tag Objects.

I have an AutoComplete function in jQuery that accepts an array of the following format:

```
    var availableTagsCustom = [
        {
            tagName: 'Ruby',
            tagDescription: 'Ruby is an open-source dynamic...'
        },
        {
            tagName: 'Scala',
            tagDescription: 'Scala is a general purpose programming language...'
        },
        {
            tagName: 'Scheme',
            tagDescription: 'Scheme is a functional programming language....'
        }
    ];
```

How do I translate or convert the "object List of Tag Objects" that I receive into this format?

Thank you.

Comment: Reading about [JSon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) and built-in [JsonSerializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) and [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) can be a good starting point

Comment: +1 for @L.B. You should use JSON.net here, and then you can convert any array or object into JSON to be passed to the client for parsing. [This is the JSON.net architecture I use when I want to convert a list into JSON.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/csjson/)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]` attribute at service class level to able to get `Json` result.

Second you need to apply `[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]` on method.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<Tag> GetTags()
{
    List<Tag> TagList = new List<Tag>();

    DataTable dt = Helpers.Tags.GetTags();

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        Tag t = new Tag();
        t.TagName = dr["Tag"].ToString();
        t.TagDescription = dr["Description"].ToString();
        TagList.Add(t);
    }

    return TagList;
}
```

Third set `Content-type: application/json` in request.

> This article also might be helpful ["using jquery to consume aspnet json web-services](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/)

Comment: After doing your suggestions according to firebug if I get the array.d I get the following:                                                                      [
         Object { 

 __type="iConnect.UI.Webservices.Tag",  
 TagName="Poll",  
 TagDescription= "Poll Tag"

 }
]                                                                                    which is not similar to the output I want, I'm not sure how to use this yet, I've researched many articles on the internet but still can't find how to do it.